# Is the same thread used for each individual HTTP transaction in IIS on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, iis, web-applications

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApp which is hosted on Azure and needs to support users from a variety of different cultures - en-GB, en-US, fr-CH, de-CH, etc.

Is the same thread used for each individual HTTP transaction in IIS on Azure, so I can be sure that the thread to which I set current Culture / UICulture upon receipt of request message from the user's browser will be the same as the thread used to deliver the response message back to the same user?

```
CultureInfo Culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Culture;
```

Are there any configuration settings on IIS or Azure that might change the situation?

Comment: As far as there are async calls at the server, the async continuation can always pick another thread to continue.

Comment: Why do you have to set thread culture? Without that you can still write culture aware code.

Comment: I am asking the question because setting the Culture of the current thread looks like the simplest way to implement culture aware code, but as pointed-out by Wiktor that does mean that I can't use any async calls. Therefore it looks like i'm stuck with things like GetString (string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture); where culture is a cookie value passed by the user containing his language preference. Do you have another other suggestions?